# Flask rename final url

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want change something like

```
page/folder_1/folder_2.../folder_n/finfolder.html
```

to

```
page/different_name
```

Code:

```
@app.route('/<path:url>')
def page(url):
    return render_template('/'+url), rename(url, 'different_name')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8viC6.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the directory else, by default Flask search HTML files in templates folder.

```
import os
from flask import Flask

template_dir = os.path.abspath('page/folder_1/folder_2.../folder_n')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir)

@app.route('/<path:url>')
def page(url):
    return render_template('finfolder.html')
```